# Webbrowser control's window.external is ALWAYS null

Tags: vb.net, browser, null

The Web browser's Window.External object is always null!

To reproduce drop a web browser on a new winform and type:

```
Option Strict Off

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load()
        Handles MyBase.LoadMe.WebBrowser1.Document.Window.DomWindow.External.AddFavorite("http://www.google.com")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Make certain you go to the Assembly Information dialog and check "Make Assembly COM-Visible."  This is necessary.

I am lost as to why with a COM visible assembly the External object is always nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you set the [ObjectForScripting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting.aspx) property to your host window? I think you need to do that for window.external to work.

Answer (score 6):

Also, ensure the object you set to ObjectForScripting has the following attributes:

```
[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
[ComVisible(true)]
```

Without it, the window.external was always null.

Comment: It was `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(true)]` that worked for me.