# Javascript/jquery in windows applications

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net, winforms

This might be a stupid question but is it possible to use javascript/jQuery in windows applications?

Im making this application in vb.net, just for personal use and im just making it to practice and to learn more about vb.net programming.

I know javascript is ment for web applications but maybe there are ways to use them in windows applications aswell.

Any response or comment is welcome.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What do you want to do with JQuery in windows forms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be able to find some success with something like [Jint](http://jint.codeplex.com/) to run JavaScript code, but JQuery relies heavily on the presence of the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), so using JQuery to work with a VB.net UI isn't going to be possible.

Answer (score 1):

[cscript](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490816.aspx), [wscript](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/wsh_runfromwindowsbasedhost.mspx?mfr=true) and the [Windows Scripting Host](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98591fh7.aspx) objects allow you to do things that you can't do from within a browser, but these are very much limited to scripting tasks, and won't allow you to create a GUI.

It is possible to create a VB application that does little more than host a browser window.  You could use such a browser window to create a rich jquery UI.

By setting the [window.external](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535246%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) property from your VB app (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/499743/webbrowser-controls-window-external-is-always-null) and [this HOWTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0746166.aspx)), you can give the embedded browser access to things outside the browser environment, thereby enabling it to interact with the local machine in a manner normally forbidden by a browser.

Answer (score 0):

I have to disappoint you, this is not possible. Unless there is some browser-emulator tool or some js-engine under the hood in your application, there is obviously no way to link those worlds.

However, if you like the javascript syntax, you can use `node.js` also on windows platforms. But there again, it is not possible to access the windows API. But there might be a plugin which allows for that.

Answer (score 0):

Write a [Metro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211386.aspx) application?

> You write Metro style apps using familiar technologies like **HTML5**,
>   **JavaScript**, and **CSS3**, or XAML, with
>   C++, C#, or **VB.Net** code-behind.

Answer (score 0):

HTML applications (HTA) may give you what you're looking for. They don't seem to get much attention these days but try changing our `.htm` suffix to `.hta` and then run it from the command line. I haven't figured out how to debug it, but hey.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [Real Oop with AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/153134-real-oop-with-autoit-meet-jsaio/) and [Smuggling Autoit into IE Embedded](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/153436-smuggling-autoit-into-ie-embedded/)

There is also JScript.NET.